# Creating crossing line elements in html page with svg

Tags: html, svg

I'd like to create two crossing lines which would look like an 'X' with svg.  I have tried the following, but only one line shows up.  Probably a really simple issue, but I haven't figured out a solution.

```html
<svg id="min-1"width="26" height="14" style="display:block">
  <line x1="4" y1="3" x2="22" y2="11" style="stroke:#5A5A5A; stroke-width:3">
  <line x1="4" y1="11" x2="22" y2="3" style="stroke:#5A5A5A; stroke-width:3">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some errors. Simply add `/` to the end of the `<line>` tags:

```html
<svg id="min-1"width="26" height="14" style="display:block">
  <line x1="4" y1="3" x2="22" y2="11" style="stroke:#5A5A5A; stroke-width:3"/>
  <line x1="4" y1="11" x2="22" y2="3" style="stroke:#5A5A5A; stroke-width:3"/>
</svg>
```